how to inspect locally running BLE GATT server on Ubuntu Linux using D-bus?
I am using following sample code:
example-gatt-server for testing purpose.
Example:
-> In this code we have registered Service: HeartRateService which has multiple  Characteristics as: HeartRateMeasurementChrc, BodySensorLocationChrc, HeartRateControlPointChrc
Service:
HeartRateService:
UUID = '0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'

Characteristic:
HeartRateMeasurementChrc:
UUID = '00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'

BodySensorLocationChrc:
UUID = '00002a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'

HeartRateControlPointChrc:
UUID = '00002a39-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'

Is there way I can inspect locally registered BLE GATT(Server) Service and Characteristics on D-Bus using busctl introspect command? same as other D-bus as when I am trying to check this implemented custom GATT Service and Characteristics on D-bus I didn't find them.
In this example used D-bus service name = '/org/bluez/example/service'
Note: I am able to query these custom created Service and Characteristics over Mobile Phone
bluez/test$ sudo python3.10 example-gatt-server 
Registering GATT application...
GetManagedObjects
GATT application registered


bluez/test$ sudo busctl tree org.bluez
└─/org
  └─/org/bluez
    └─/org/bluez/hci0
      └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37
        ├─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service0006
        │ └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service0006/char0007
        │   └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service0006/char0007/desc0009
        ├─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service000a
        │ ├─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service000a/char000b
        │ └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service000a/char000d
        ├─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service000f
        │ └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service000f/char0010
        │   ├─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service000f/char0010/desc0012
        │   └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service000f/char0010/desc0013
        └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service0014
          └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service0014/char0015
            ├─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service0014/char0015/desc0017
            └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_B5_4F_44_A8_37/service0014/char0015/desc0018
 


Have you tried just "sudo busctl tree"?

@Emil yes I have tried that too I am not able to find this newly defined BLE GATT service and characteristic on D-Bus . Seems bluez doesn't support exposing implemented custom BLE GATT service and characteristic interface on D-bus
